# jquery conflicting

Tags: jquery, conflict

I have a contact form that slides out on a full screen gallery page. The jquery code is conflicting and messing up the gallery. Any ideas?
I've tried deleting the second jquery library and even adding noconflict function within each script.

```
<body>
<div id="gallery_nav" style="height:30px;padding-top:5px;">
 <div class="logo"><a href="/">df</a></div>
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/about">About Me</a>
<a href="/specials">Specials</a>
</div>

<div id="contactable"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2    /jquery.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/contactme/jquery.contactable.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/contactme/contactable.css" type="text/css" />
<script>
contact form scripts goes here
</script>

<div for full screen images goes here>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
script for image gallery goes here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch : gallery first (1.3), and scripts after (1.7.2).

Try to replace $ by jQuery with jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Do I add that within the <script> tag?